# Passing parent id to child record in VisualForce page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I'm attempting to create my first VF page. It is a line-item entry form that will allow a user to enter multiple child records (Enfants_*c) before clicking save. Right now, I'm opening the VF page from a custom button on the parent (Assure*_c). However, when the page opens, the lookup field for the parent is not populated - so the user has to click the lookup to select the parent from Assure__c. Is there a way to pass the parent id of the previous page to the new child records on the VF page ?

```
//page    

<apex:page standardController="Enfants__c" extensions="insererEnfants" standardStylesheets="true">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Ajouter un enfant"
    subtitle="{!$User.FirstName}" help="/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?loc=help"></apex:sectionHeader>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Nouveau enfant" id="thePageBlock" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Enregistrer"></apex:commandButton>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="   Annuler   "></apex:commandButton>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accts}" var="a" id="table">
            <apex:facet name="footer">
                <apex:commandLink value="Ajouter" action="{!addRow}" rerender="table,error"/>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:commandLink value="Supprimer" action="{!deleteRow}" rerender="table,error"/>
            </apex:facet>

            <apex:column headerValue="Nom">
                <apex:inputField/> value="{!a.Parent__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Nom">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Prénom">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Prenom__c}"/>
            </apex:column> 
                            <apex:column headerValue="Né le">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Date_de_naissance__c}"/>
            </apex:column>   
                            <apex:column headerValue="Lieu de naissance">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Lieu_de_naissance__c}"/>
            </apex:column>   
                            <apex:column headerValue="Situation">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Situation__c }"/>
            </apex:column>                          
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>


//Controller


public class insererEnfants{


public List<Enfants__c> accts {get; set;}


public insererEnfants(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    accts = new List<Enfants__c>();
    accts.add(new Enfants__c();

}

public void addrow(){
    accts.add(new Enfants__c());       
}

public PageReference deleteRow(){
   if (accts.size()>1)
   {
      accts.remove(accts.size()-1);
   }
   return null;
}

public PageReference save()
{
    insert accts;
    Assure__c theParent = new Assure__c(id=accts[0].Parent__c);
    PageReference acctPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(theParent).view();
    acctPage.setRedirect(true);
    return acctPage;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have no reference to the Parent object.  You can solve this two ways:

**Solution 1:**

Pass the ID of the parent using a URL button, with something like the following as the URL:

```
/apex/EnfantsPage?assureid={!Assure_c.Id}
```

Replace "EnfantsPage" with the name of your VF page.  Then, within the controller:

```
String assureid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('assureid');
```

Now you know the ID of the parent.  When you create a new child record, set the value of the parent id to id you have passed.

```
public insererEnfants(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
  accts = new List<Enfants__c>();
  if (assureid <> null) {
    for (Assure__c assure: [ SELECT Id FROM Assure__c
                             WHERE Id = :assureid] ) {
    accts.add(new Enfants__c( Parent__c = assure.Id ));
  } else {
    accts.add(new Enfants__c());  
  }
}

public void addrow(){
  if (assure.Id <> null) {
    accts.add(new Enfants__c( Parent__c = assure.Id ));
  } else {
    accts.add(new Enfants__c());  
  }      
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Instead of extending the child controller, extend the parent:

```
public Assure__c parent {get;}
public List<Enfants__c> accts {get; set;}
public insererEnfants(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
  this.parent = (Assure__c)stdcontroller.getRecord();
  accts.add(new Enfants__c( Parent__c = parent.id );
}

public void addrow(){
  accts.add(new Enfants__c( Parent__c = parent.id );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my problem is in inserting the ID in the base, I should modify the controller to insert the ID of the parent.

Comment: The problem is that you are not defining the parent when you create the child records, nor are you setting it anywhere else.  Try this: accts.add(new Enfants__c(Parent__c=assureid));

Comment: I obtain this error `Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: assureid at line 9 column 44` and that is my problem, I didn't finde a solution for a mouth until I founded this http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Passing-parent-id-to-child-record-in-VisualForce-page/td-p/111007 and I can't do the same with this problem

Comment: Looking again, I see now that you are not retrieving the record for the standard controller.  I will change my answer as I now understand the root problem.